# Is it possible to store asp web controls in a string and render as proper html?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to store html in a string so I can dynamically add html blocks to a page on load. I have a class called SearchFilters that looks like this:

```
public class SearchFilters
{
public string FilterName { get; set; }
public bool Show { get; set; }
public string htmlString { get; set; }

public SearchFilters(string name)
{
    FilterName = name;
    Show = false;
    htmlString = "";
}
}
```

I want to be able to add the html to the htmlString property and then on page load I only want to print out the html blocks for the search filters that have a Show property set to true;

Basically the one html block I'm working with right now is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="ProNum"><asp:Literal runat="server" Text="Order No:" /></label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ProNum" Placeholder="Pro #" CssClass="form-control" type="number" />
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to be able to create a string in my aspx.cs page like this:

```
filtersList = new List<SearchFilters>();
SearchFilters filter;

filter = new SearchFilters("OrderNo");
filter.Show = false;
filter.htmlString = @"<label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="ProNum"><asp:Literal runat="server" Text="Order No:" /></label>
                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ProNum" Placeholder="Pro #" CssClass="form-control" type="number" />
                      </div>";
filtersList.Add(filter);
```

And then in my aspx page I'm trying to grab it like this::

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <%foreach (var filter in filtersList) { %>
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <%= filter.htmlString %>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

When I inspect the page I see the div tags there like I expect them too but the margins are negative and the height is very small so I can't actually see the textbox.

I was trying to simplify my approach and I tried it without the asp web controls and it seemed to work.

Is it even possible to keep the asp web controls in and do it this way (or in a similar way)?

Comment: No. You can do this with plain HTML, but not with server side controls. Their events won't be wired up properly. You would actually need to create the control on the server side (not via a string) in the correct lifecycle event.

Comment: you can still use conditional logic to decide whether web controls are added or not, (or whether they're displayed or not, which might be simpler)

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong here but can't you use `@Html.Raw("some html")` helper to do this?

Comment: @DavidLee No, first of all that's Razor syntax, which isn't applicable in Web Forms. Secondly, you can't create Web Forms controls by creating strings containing the markup.

Comment: @mason Gotcha, did not know Web Forms does not support that.

Comment: @DavidLee Think about how Web Forms works. The ASPX markup has to be run through the Web Forms engine to generate HTML markup. If  you were to do something like `<% GetSomeASPXMarkup() %>` it would just embed the ASPX markup in the resulting HTML, and the browser won't have any idea what an `<asp:TextBox>` is because browsers only know normal HTML elements, not ASP.NET Web Forms server side controls. A lot of people assume that `<asp:TextBox>` runs on the client, it's a common misunderstanding with people new to Web Forms. It's not magic.

Comment: @mason That makes sense, I guess I am too used to ASP MVC and ASP Core where you are able to use standard HTML.

Comment: @DavidLee You can use standard HTML in Web Forms too. Nothing would prevent you from being able to do `<% GetSomeHTML() %>`. But most Web Forms developers either don't know to do that or want to avoid it because they then can't go `TextBox1.Text` and instead have to dig the values out of the `Request.Form`. And honestly, once you move away from Web Forms controls, you might as well switch to MVC and Razor anyways, at least you pick up the model binder that way. But somehow many people have gotten it in their heads that MVC is harder than Web Forms, because they overestimate the Web Forms magic

Comment: @mason I learned Web Forms first in college and after that class I moved to MVC and never looked back.  MVC imo is way easier and promotes developers to make code that is easier to maintain.